# magento 2 getting error on update product action in admin panel

Tags: magento2, php, error, backend

I am getting the below error in the magento admin panel while editing the product options from the action dropdown.
Catalog - products. Select a product or 2. Then actions menu select change attribute

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/domain/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/action/inventory.phtml on line 135

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please help me with the above question

Answer (score 0):

Open the file /magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/action/inventory.phtml and you will see a core_config_data value is used there, now open the database and open core_config_data table search for "min_sale_qty" in path column, correct the value set it to some integer value
This should resolve the issue